# Yii2: Calling unknown method: backend\controllers\UserController::findModel()

Tags: methods, yii2, edit

Have Yii2 project to create my own blog, I can view the list of index to show data from database, but I need to access to **foreach** and be able to access to edit page, then the problem comes out.
Here is my code for **edit** in **UserController**:

```
  namespace backend\controllers;

  use yii\web\Controller;
  use common\models\User;
  use Yii;

public function actionIndex(){

    $query = User::find();
    $count = $query->count();
    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount'=>$count, 'pageSize'=>5]);
    $results = $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();

    return $this->render('index',['results'=>$results,'pagination'=>$pagination]);
}

  public function actionEdit($id){
    // $id = (int)$id;
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    return $this->render('edit',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

Here is the code for my **edit view**:

```
<div class="inner-container">
    <?=Html::beginForm(['user/edit'],'post',['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','class'=>'form-horizontal', 'id'=>'addForm'])?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?=Html::label('Username*：','username',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-2 col-md-1'])?>
            <div class="controls col-sm-10 col-md-11">
                <?=Html::activeInput('text',$model,'username',['class'=>'form-control input'])?>
                <?=Html::error($model,'username',['class'=>'error'])?>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <?=Html::label('Email*：','email',['class'=>'control-label col-sm-2 col-md-1'])?>
            <div class="controls col-sm-10 col-md-11">
                <?=Html::activeInput('email',$model,'email',['class'=>'form-control input'])?>
                <?=Html::error($model,'email',['class'=>'error'])?>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sort_order" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-1">Password：</label>           
            <div class="controls col-sm-10 col-md-11">
                <?=Html::activeInput('password',$model,'password',['class'=>'form-control input input-small'])?>
                <?=Html::error($model,'password',['class'=>'error'])?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="status" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-1">Status：</label>         
            <div class="controls col-sm-10 col-md-11">
                <?=Html::activeDropDownList($model,'status',ArrayHelper::map($active,'statusID','statusCN'),['class'=>'form-control width_auto'])?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
                <?=Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>

                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?=Url::to(['index'])?>">Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?=Html::endForm()?>
</div>
```

The code above is working to create/add a new record, but then error on editing the item.

> Calling unknown method: backend\controllers\UserController::findModel()

I tried to change to **actionEdit** method,with following code:

```
public function actionEdit($id){
//change here
$model = User::findOne($id);

if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

return $this->render('edit',['model'=>$model]);
```

}

Then it shows:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

No idea what is wrong with my code. The User Model is extended **ActiveRecord**.

parts of view index:

```
<tbody>
        <?php foreach($results as $user){?>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?=$user['id']?>">
        </td>
        <td><?=$user['username']?></td>
        <td><?=$user['email']?></td>
        <td><?=$user['login_ip']?></td>
        <td><?=date('Y-m-d',$user['create_date'])?></td>
        <td><?=($user['status'] == 0) ? "NonActived" : "Actived" ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?=Url::to(['edit','id'=>$user['id']])?>" title="Edit" class="data_op data_edit"></a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Delete" class="data_op data_delete">edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

The above Edit link can show as:

> http://xx/yii2AdvancedBlog/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fedit&id=2

but once click the edit button, it shows the first error.

```
<hr>
```

Update questions

---

[image: this is add action]
    [image: this is UserController]
    [image: index display]
    [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you call the wrong action

In your code  you have

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['user/add'],'post',['......
```

this mean you are call the action add od the controller user .. but you are talking about edit action  .. could be that you need

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['user/edit'],'post',['
```

For Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

be sure you have a proper $result in your action and then in the rendered  view

try test

```
if (is_array($results) || is_object($results))
{
     foreach ($results as $user) {
      ...
      }
} else {

  var_dump('$result is invalid';
}
```

Then seems you don't have a findModel function so assuming you have a User class with and id field try using this code

```
public function actionEdit($id){
  // $id = (int)$id;
  // $model = $this->findModel($id);
  $model = User::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();

  if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()){
      return $this->redirect(['index']);
  }

  return $this->render('edit',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that correction, have corrected and tested again, the same error message, any ideas where is wrong?

Comment: I have update the answer .. could be you not have a proper $results

Comment: actually, I searched other threads and have tried it before, but it would cause more errors such as **->load()** issue, then I reverse **User::findOne($id)** back to **$this->findModel($id)**, right now, I may skip others but try to fix the **$this->findMode** error. Any helps is really appreciated.

Comment: let's proceed in an orderly way, because you wrote a lot of code, and can not understand what you mean exactly .. therefore clearly show me the error you are referring to and where in the code the error occurs (if it occurs in a view show me what is the action that invokes) ..And 'also appropriate that you eliminate all the code that does not expressly refer to the problem you want to solve ..

Comment: hi, I just updated and upload some images that I want to show like **actionAdd**, you can check my update on the questions, there are image links. And the error message I have. (I just add $status[] that I found is missed in edit). Those images may explain my code more clearly and the effort I want to archive. Thank you sooooo much to help me.

Comment: I .. begin to understand .. just a few  more  info . 1 ) your controller don't extend  . a controller class ...why ? .. from  which class you have obtained the code for  User controller .. 2) seems that you don't have a findModel() function .. this could be related to the fact your controller is not  an extension of a User controller .. then explain me how you have the User Controller /Model  and so on ..

Comment: Hi, you can see the second picture, the **UserController** indeed **extends Controller**, at very top of the code, otherwise, my other actionIndex & actionAdd would not work. That UserController is relate to my User model. Or what do I miss...

Comment: I have update the answer with a suggestion .. let me know

Comment: Holly GOD, you save it. It is working! Only thing is that you may adjust the answer **$model = User::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();** with "[]" in where parameter. Just wondering why findModel() exists for my Gii testing file? I use Gii to generate template and it works, but not on my code.

Comment: @newbrant   .. [] adjusted and answer updated .. User is an indentity and extend the identity interface .. this could be the reason that gii don't have added findModel .. (It 'just a hypothesis with I had no way to verify)  if you find my answer useful you can also rate the answer as useful ..

Comment: thank you, this issue has confused me two days. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

using this  `$model = User::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();`
instead of this   `$model = $this->findModel($id)` solved a similar issue I had